# Unable to get JDBC to permanently update my database file in Eclipse

Tags: jdbc, ucanaccess

I have created a database file "accounts.accdb" and I'm using the UCanAccess JDBC driver in Eclipse to access it. I can access it fine and update it using my server application but when I close my server application the contents of the database file return to their initial values. My code is below, I have tried using `commit()` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://accounts.accdb");

//STEP 4: Set auto commit as false.
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

//STEP 5: Execute a query to create statment with
// required arguments for RS example.
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
           ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);



// Step 6: Execute a SQL SELECT Update.
String sql = "update bankAccounts set " + field + "= " + newValue + " where id = " + id;
System.out.println("update command: " + sql);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
System.out.println("Database is updated!!!!");

//STEP 7: Commit data here.
conn.commit();

//STEP 8: Clean-up environment
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: `executeUpdate` returns an `int` value indicating the number of rows affected. Is that value greater than zero?

Comment: Yes it returns one, which is what I expect since it only updates one row

Comment: Try `System.out.println(((UcanaccessConnection)conn).getDbIO().getFile().getAbsolutePath());` to see if the .accdb file that UCanAccess is updating is the same as what you think it is updating.

Comment: What's the UCanAccess version you're using? What's the table bankAccounts structure(all columns types)?

Comment: I tried to run the print command above but eclipse doesn't know what UcanaccessConnection is, should I replace this with some other variable or object?                                                                                                             The UcanAccess version I'm using is 3.0.7, and all the columns should be string type I think

Comment: *"eclipse doesn't know what UcanaccessConnection is"* - You need `import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection;` at the top of your .java file.

Comment: I can't see any UcanaccessConnection under "net.ucanaccess.jdbc" , the only class I can see under this is UcanloadDriver

Comment: `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection` is a class inside `ucanaccess-3.0.7.jar`. If you have `ucanaccess-3.0.7.jar` included as an external library in your Build Path then Eclipse will be able to find `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection` when it processes your `import` statement.

Comment: I was missing the ucanaccess-3.0.7.jar file from by build path, once I added it to the project I was able to run that command and I am now able to permanently update database file ... that was the issue all along thanks very much for the help!!!!